# Python Panda Dataframe Replace Value in a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using a csv which has 4 column separated by comma

```
A,B,C,D
emp1,london,comp1,123@emp
emp2,london,comp1,@456emp2
emp3,london,comp1,125465@emp_
emp4,london,comp1,98576-emp_@
```

In the output I want to first use | as a delimiter instead of comma
Second from the column D I want to keep only integers so my output will look

```
A,B,C,D
emp1|london|comp1|123
emp2|london|comp1|4562
emp3|london|comp1|125465
emp4|london|comp1|98576
```

I want to do this using panda dataframe.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding the first part, to_csv lets you set the deliminter, so use sep=('|').
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY with regex (replace everything that is not a digit with empty string `''` ):

```
df.D = df.D.str.replace('\D', '' , regex =True)
df.to_csv('<your csv file name here>', sep = '|')
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
|A|B|C|D
0|emp1|london|comp1|123
1|emp2|london|comp1|4562
2|emp3|london|comp1|125465
3|emp4|london|comp1|98576
```

Comment: do you mean to say - df["D"] = df["D"].str.replace('\D', '' , regex =True) ?

Comment: yup @RahulWagh. It's just another way to write!!

Comment: It works perfectly thanks. Now if I want to store rows from a file in another file which has value in D column like emp5|london|comp1|AVP_123-456   
                        emp6|london|comp1|AVP_PQR-123-456 and which does not match this format in another file